# Integration Gitlab and jira 6.x

Tags: jira, gitlab-ci, jira-rest-api

I tried the integration of Gilab and Jira in your version 6.x, I check the log system, I have one error bad request.

`{"severity":"ERROR","time":"2019-04-29T18:04:49.796Z","correlation_id":"ca0a028e-c6e6-468c-a47d-e78bed7d11d4","service_class":"JiraService","project_id":72,"project_path":"prueba/prueba","message":"Issue transition failed","error":"Bad Request","client_url":"http://jira.developer.com.co:9900"}`

**my setting in gitlab**

[image]

**Jira setting**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about your JIRA API URL ? In Jira 6, it's not enabled by default. Make sure the 'Allow Remote API Calls' is turned ON under Administration > General Configuration.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasPepinster, 

The option Allow Remote API Calls is active